# How to Grab Anime info using Jikan API and fill the value in Metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, api

I want to create an Anime website. But I find it less effective if I have to manually copy & paste Anime information from [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net). So I want to create a system where users must enter the Anime ID from [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net) and after that press the generate button, then automatically the desired Anime information will be filled in [Metabox](https://metabox.io). Oh, my `post_type` is `anime`.
Here's the endpoint:

```
https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/{id}
```

And this is my Metabox:

```
<?php
/* Metabox Tweak */
if ( ! function_exists( 'rwmb_meta' ) ) {
    function rwmb_meta( $key, $args = '', $post_id = null ) {
        return false;
    }
}

/* Anime Metabox */
function mal_metabox( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = 'mal_';
    
    $meta_boxes[] = [
        'id' => 'anime_info',
        'title' => esc_html__( 'Anime Details' ),
        'post_types' => [ 'anime' ],
        'context' => 'advanced',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'autosave' => true,
        'fields' => [
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'title_japanese',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Japanese' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Japanese Title' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'title_english',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'English' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'English Title' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'title_synonyms',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Synonmys' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Synonyms Title' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'status',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Status' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Anime Status' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'types',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Type' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Anime Type' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'source',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Source' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Anime Source' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'duration',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Duration' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Anime Duration' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'episodes',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Total Episodes' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Total Episodes' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'seasons',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Seasons' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Seasons' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'studios',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Studios' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Studios' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'producers',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Producers' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Producers' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'releases',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Releases' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Release Date' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'genres',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Genres' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Genres' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'score',
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Score' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Score' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'synopsis',
                'type' => 'text_area',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Synopsis' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Synopsis' ),
            ],
            [
                'id' => $prefix . 'poster',
                'type' => 'file_input',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Poster' ),
                'desc' => esc_html__( 'Anime Poster' ),
                'max_file_uploads' => '1',
                'max_status' => false,
            ],
        ],
    ];
    return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter('rwmb_meta_box', 'mal_metabox');

/* INPUT */
function generate_info($post) {
?>
<div class="rwmb-meta-box">
    <div class="rwmb-field rwmb-text-wrapper">
        <div class="rwmb-label">
            <label for="anime-id">Jikan API</label>     
        </div>
        <div class="rwmb-input ui-shortable">
            <div class="rwmb-clone rwmb-text-clone">
                <input size="30" type="text" id="anime-id" class="rwmb-text" name="anime-id" placeholder="Enter Anime ID"/>
            </div>
            <a class="button-primary" id="generate">Generate</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}

/* Show The Form */
function add_generate_info() {
    add_metabox('generate_anime', 'Generate Info', 'generate_info', 'anime');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_generate_info');
```

Comment: Probably you need to do a bit more work to make your question more specific. You might have several steps here: figure out how to get data from the API, see if you want to do that from the browser or server, figure out how the data from the API maps to the fields in your metabox and write code that connects them all up. Personally I would start with just figuring out how to talk to the API from PHP or javascript, then connect it to Wordpress next.

Comment: Ohh like that, thanks for the advice. I will do it.

Comment: WP has `wp_remote_get()` function, which you can use to make requests to API, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/